# How can I call MMC Snap-In to Import Certificates

Tags: .net, winforms, mmc

I'm working on an application to a client and he asked me to make call to the MMC Import Certificate Wizard and also the Export Certificate Wizard.

Even I told him we can develop an "internal and easier routine" to perform these jobs, my client told me that all his employees are very used to these common Windows interfaces, so, I need to utilize them in my system.

So, my question:
**how can I call MMC.EXE directly to the IMPORT and EXPORT wizards using .NET?**

Thank you very much for any help;